# Overriding the User entity list_builder handler

Tags: 8, users

I'm trying to override the User entity list_builder handler to add another column to the table and implement some JavaScript search functionality.

The code I'm using is below which is in my modules mm.module file.

```
function mm_user_override_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['user']->setHandlerClass('list_builder', 'Drupal\mm_user_list_builder\UserListBuilder');
}
```

The issue I'm having is this code gives me the following error

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException</em>: The &quot;user&quot; entity type did not specify a list_builder handler.
```

Which from what I can tell is not correct, even `$entity_types['user']->getHandlerClasses()` tells me the `list_builder` handler exists.

Why is this error happening & how best to resolve it? Or is there a better way for me to add a column & search to the user list page?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the approach. Might be a small error, like for example the module name in hook and fully-qualified class name are not the same, in case this is not intentionally.

Comment: Thanks @4k4 , it's good to know I'm on the right lines but still cannot see what's causing the problem. Might see if the examples module has anything I could look at.

Answer (score 1):

my_module.module :

```
<?php

use Drupal\my_module\MyModuleListBuilder;

function my_module_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['user']->setHandlerClass('list_builder', MyModuleListBuilder::class);
// $entity_types['user']->setListBuilderClass(MyModuleListBuilder::class); // Other solution possible
}
```

my_module\src\MyModuleUserListBuilder.php :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\user\UserListBuilder;

class MyModuleListBuilder extends UserListBuilder {
    // Implement the function you want to edit
}
```